# Very bad FPS on DOTA 2 with Ubuntu 13.10 using HD7770

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, games, troubleshooting

I am having very bad FPS on DOTA 2 native.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 13.10 for X64 bit systems
- AMD FX-6300 CPU
- 8GB DDR3 - 1600MHZ
- Radeon 7770 GHZ Edition with 14.1 Beta Drivers

What I have tried up so far:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - same problem
- AMD 13.12 Catalyst - same problem
- Source Drivers - same problem
- Proprietary drivers provided by Ubuntu - Steam won't launch

Is it possible to help to helm me out with this very troublesome problem. This is the only game that I do play in my free time on the PC.

Regards,
P. Mihai

Comment: Any answers?!??

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this one by myself.

- Upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04.
- Made sure that *Radeon dynamic power management* (dpm) is enabled in grub file (see [Radeon Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver))
- used the Open Source Graphics Driver from the [Oibaf ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

And that's it. Everything works like a charm.